# Passing Strings to /bin/login

Tags: linux, bash, authentication, expect

I'm in the process of creating a login wrapper for /bin/login so that when you boot Linux you get a TUI Login instead of the bland login on the tty console. This will be just a bash script for this wrapper, however I'm wondering how / if can pass the users username and password to /bin/login in one or two lines.

Todo this I would think you could do

```
echo "username/npassword" | login
```

But it didn't work. At least that's what I'm getting on my terminal.
I've considered except shell but it spawns under the user. Can anyone redirect me in the right direction?

Comment: What is TUI login? If you only want a custom message to be displayed, you can have a look at `/etc/issue` file.

Comment: Text User Interface it's going to based off of the ncurses library under the dialog command.

Comment: The login command already allows you to specify a user name so why not use that? As for the password, why not do likewise and add a `--pasword` option?

Comment: Hi there, Did you finally found a solution to this? I'm also looking for it. Thanks.